# orderByChild is not working in Ionic3 with firebase npm package

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using Ionic & [firebase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase) and here is my query

```
firebase.database().ref('categories')
.orderByChild('lastAdded').once('value').then(function(data){
// Show Data here ...
});
```

But the data is not ordered by lastAdded child.

The same orderByChild works well for me in VueJS app, however in Ionic this doesn't work.

Comment: Have you added  `".indexOn":"lastAdded"` to your security rules?

Comment: Yes, like this 
{
  "rules": {
"categories": {
     ".read": true,
        ".write" : "auth != null",
      ".indexOn": ["lastAdded", "name"]
    }
}
}